# C# WPF Webbrowser msHTML - Explore DOM - Find Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, dom, browser, mshtml

I'm actually working on a personal project in C# using WPF and WPF WebBrowser. I really need to explore html DOM Elements as we used to do in javascript or php..etc

In my MainWindow I have this variable :

```
private mshtml.HTMLDocument mainDocument = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
```

In my webBrowser LoadComplete callback I have this :

```
mainDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument) mainBrowser.Document;
```

Ok, so this is nice, it's working.

Now if I do this :

```
mshtml.IHTMLElement elem = mainDocument.getElementById("MY_ID");
```

it's also very nice, can do elem.innerHTML or somes stuff like that.

BUT my problem is only HTMLDocument have methodes to find elements by ID, by tagnames..etc

I don't know how to find elements in IHTMLElement. I tried some stuff like casting IHTMLElement to IHTMLElement2..etc but nothing have worked.

Please if you have any ideas. A lot of people talks about hosting winforms webbrowser but I think it must have a way to do that only with mshtml.

Thanks a lot,
If you need more information, please feel free to ask me

ps : I'm french so I'm sorry about my Engish skills

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse HTML document in Winforms or wpf, you can use an excellent parser htmlagility pack. Refer to below link
http://html-agility-pack.net

```
  var url = "http://html-agility-pack.net/";
 var web = new HtmlWeb();
 var doc = web.Load(url);
```

After loading it in doc, you can get any attribute, tag, etc.

```
 var value = doc.DocumentNode
.SelectNodes("//td/input")
.First()
.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

It's super easy, just explore the doc a bit and you can make full use of it.

You can load html agility pack even from webbrowser, like below

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new 
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream);
```

Or you can do like this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new 
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(webBrowser1.Document);
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, but what if we already have a HTML document in the WPF WebBrowser's `Document` property? Could we possibly access its entire HTML and initialize HtmlAgilityPack from that, without reloading the document?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Below is how you will do it

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new 
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.Load(webBrowser1.DocumentStream);

Or you can do like this

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new 
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.Load(webBrowser1.Document);

I just edited my above answer to include above change.

Comment: If an answer helps, do mark it as Answer, this way others can also benefit.

Comment: You really would like but I cannot because I'm new member, I will put more details in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Sujit for your help.
I've not enouth reputation to mark your answer as helpful but I hope others will do.

To get it work with wpf webbrowser I've done :

```
mainHTMLDoc.LoadHtml((mainBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument).documentElement.innerHTML);
```

To manipulate everything in should use this :

```
using System.Linq;
```

After that you can do stuffs like that :

```
var table = mainHTMLDoc.GetElementbyId("MyID");
var rows = table.Element("tbody").Elements("tr");
for(int i=0; i< rows.Count();i++) {
    var datacol1 = rows.ElementAt(i).Elements("td").ElementAt(0).Descendants("a").ElementAt(0).InnerHtml;
    var datacol2 = rows.ElementAt(i).Elements("td").ElementAt(1).InnerText 
}
```

Whitout using Linq you cannot use Elements function which are very very usefull !
Thanks again Sujit :)

Comment: No issues Mickael. All the best!